# More concise way of grouping characters in a String

Tags: java, roman-numerals

I'm practicing roman numeral addition in Java. based on the rules of eliminating subtractive notation, combining, then grouping into higher value equivalents, here's what "IV" + "IV" would look like:

1. "IV" + "IV"
2. "IIII" + "IIII"
3. "IIIIIIII"
4. "VIII" (converting 5 I's "IIIII" into "V")

I'm using the code below to group the 8 I's into "IIIII" and "III". I can then convert "IIIII" into "V" using a `Map` (not shown). Can the grouping code below be written using `Stream` methods?

```
     private String[] group(String sortedRawSum) {
        List<String> groupedChars = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        while (i+5 < sortedRawSum.length()) {
            if ( sortedRawSum.substring(i, i+5).equals("IIIII") ) {
                groupedChars.add("IIIII");
                i += 5;
                continue;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (i < sortedRawSum.length()) {
            groupedChars.add(sortedRawSum.substring(i));
        }

        return groupedChars.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed, that the `sortedRawSum`-parameter only contains `I`s?

Comment: if i can get the only `I`s figured out, i was thinking i could adapt it to be more generic?